# Xml Pull Parser exception unexpected token position text

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am trying to build a simple webservice in ASP.net with client on Android platform. I'm using Soap library for the connection client. Although I get the result what I want but still it shows as an error in logcat. I want to know what is the problem here.

MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String SOAP_Action = "http://tempuri.org/register";
        String METHOD = "register";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        String URL = "http://myIP/Service.asmx";


        try {
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

            Request.addProperty("name", params[0]);
            Request.addProperty("city", params[1]);
            Request.addProperty("address", params[2]);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);
            transportSE.call(SOAP_Action, envelope);
            resultString = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Log.d(TAG, "Data Added " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Logcat:

```
04-21 13:08:15.827 28309-28309/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=314.26392, y[0]=308.14453, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2728472, downTime=2725037, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-21 13:08:15.827 28309-28309/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=314.26392, y[0]=308.14453, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2728472, downTime=2725037, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-21 13:08:15.827 28309-28309/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=314.26392, y[0]=308.14453, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2728472, downTime=2725037, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap E/Response of Service: Error: Unexpected token (position:TEXT Entry Added Succ...@1:24 in java.io.InputStreamReader@a61dd4e) 
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT Entry Added Succ...@1:24 in java.io.InputStreamReader@a61dd4e) 
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:432)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2048)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:301)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:274)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap.Register$RegisterAsyncTask.doInBackground(Register.java:105)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap.Register$RegisterAsyncTask.doInBackground(Register.java:47)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
04-21 13:08:22.010 28309-5265/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-21 13:08:22.012 28309-28322/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-21 13:08:22.012 28309-28322/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f7f5f999780, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-21 13:08:22.098 28309-28322/com.example.krupal.webserviceusingsoap E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7f56994930
```

As 4th line in Logcat says that text added successfully but still it is an error not success.

Need help to understand the error.

**Update/Answer:**

Problem was coming from the webservice, and not from the Andriod coding side.